# How to sort an array of objects by property when some of the properties are undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of objects which contains undefined properties.

```
const arr2 = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "firstName": "tommy",
        "surname": "JONS",
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "firstName": "arnaud",
        "surname": "browny",
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "firstName": null,
        "surname": null,
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "firstName": "EMILY",
        "surname": "BOEKOEROSHE",

    }
];

function _copyAndSort<T>(items: T[], columnKey: string, isSortedDescending?: boolean): T[] {
        const key = columnKey as keyof T;
        return items.slice(0).sort((a: T, b:T) => isSortedDescending ?
        (a[key] ? a[key] < b[key] ? 1 : -1 : 1) :
        (a[key] ? a[key] > b[key]  ? 1 : -1 : 1) );
  }

    const v = _copyAndSort(arr2,"firstName",false);
    console.table(v);
```

Sorting by Id (number):

```
const v = _copyAndSort(arr2,"Id",false);
console.table(v);
```

When I try to compare by firstName, i.e., string, I get an unordered array.

```
-EMILY
-arnaud
-tommy
-null
-
```

The problem is that the properties could be empty, null, undefined and names are not always in the right casing.

- Nulls and undefined should be last.
- fields can be of different types.
- It should be case insensitive.

Comment: why don't you cast and edit the objects into 'correct' strings before sorting them?

Comment: What order are you looking for?  Should `null` be first or last?  Should the comparison be case-insensitive?  What if the field to compare is not a `string`?

Comment: @jcalz nulls and undefined should be last. And fields can be of different types. It should be case insensitive.

Comment: @Skin_phil fields can be of different types.

Comment: Which comes first? `"hello"`, or `{ key: "value" }`, or `["foo"]` or `42`?

Comment: "fields can be of different types" is confusing to me. Can you show an example of what that implies for your desired sort order?

Comment: @jcalz what I meant was that sorting can be done by different properties, like firstName (string), surname (string), id (number). If user clicks on Id column then list (array) is sorted by Id which is a number.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9bE3m) is what you're looking for? Please test against your use cases and get back to me. If it works for your needs I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?